# Plotting datasets with same shape (numpy shape) but different physical size and position

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization, mayavi

I am trying to visualize an astrophysics simulation using Mayavi or matplotlib. I am given a lot of files which all contain datacubes with (25,25,25) indices. They represent a planet (or the formation of a planet) and have a physical position and different physical size. Is there a way to scale the datasets, like adding them into a plot where they can be scaled according to there physical size and placed according to their position?

Fx: I have a data set konsisting of dimension 25*25*25 indices from koordinate (178, 178, 178) on the planet and the dataset represents the  physical size (0.62, 0.62, 0.62). And another dataset with also dimension 25*25*25 indices from kooordinate (6, 6, 6) and size (0.11, 0.11, 0.11). How to add them to one array (or plot) so they are scaled according to their physical position and size?

Comment: In general terms, you could pick a common spatial scale (for example it could be the same as that of your most finely sampled dataset), then upsample the other datasets to the same scale using some form of interpolation (see `scipy.interpolate`, `scipy.ndimage.interpolation`). It's not clear to me what you mean by "add them to one array" - do you literally want to compute their sum, or did you mean something more complicated? You mention plotting, but you haven't described what sort of plot you want to make.

Comment: By adding them to one array, means, all datasets consists of 25*25*25 numpy arrays and are added into one big array and then plotted. Is there a way that you can add the datasets one at a time to the plot and then scale them? The plots I use are mayavi quiver3d, volume or streamlines, but I can't see how it is important which plot I make.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "add" - do you mean that the values in the big array should literally be the *sums* of the values in the smaller arrays, or do you mean to combine them in some other way?

Comment: The reason I asked what sort of plot you want to make is because you've tagged your question with [tag:visualization], [tag:matplotlib] and [tag:mayavi] (!), plus the type of plot you want to make will determine the data format you require. The `contour3D`, `quiver3d` and `flow` plotting functions in `mayavi.mlab` all accept `x, y, z` coordinate vectors, so can't you just scale and offset these according to the physical dimensions and positions of your sub-arrays?

Comment: By adding I meant put them into an array, not sum, yes something more complicated. I have used flow and quiver3d. In those I had 3 matrices which contained x, y and z values and plotted them. But the koordinates was determined by the indexes of the arrays which didn't work for me, because all indexes are treated equally.

Comment: "the koordinates was determined by the indexes of the arrays which didn't work for me" - yes, as I said you could offset and scale these according to the physical dimensions and relative positions of the subarrays you want to plot

Answer (score 0):

Now quite sure about your question. If I am wrong please let me know. My understanding is you have lots of files and you want to plot all files into a single plot by planet size or position?

You might be able to load multiple files by using glob and pandas dataframe:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from path import path

document = []
p = path("C:\Users\....")  #your data path
for f in p.files(pattern='*.csv'):  # loop thourgh all files depends on your file type
    with open (f) as file:
        data = file.read()
        document.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(document)
```

Then you can sort your data in dataframe by size and position with:

```
df.sort(column='size',ascending=True)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have edited my question so hopefully it will be more clear :)

Comment: I see. Maybe you can use: `df1 = pd.read_csv('your_file_1.csv')` and 
use `all_data = pd.append(df1,df2,df3.....)` to append each file so that we will combine to same dataframe. And then you can sort all_data

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for. I don't need to sort the data. Right now I'm plotting the data according to its position. Fx. if there are 10 different coordinate positions, then the smallest position is in the first row, the second position is in the second and so on. But it doesn't really work, because the physical positions are not evenly spaced, and the physical size is also different. Hope this makes sense.